# Xamarin C# - Changes in code does not change working of the program

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i am making an app for android 6.0 using this tutorial
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/

And it is working, but when I change some line - for example I comment/delete this line

```
_imageView.SetImageBitmap (App.bitmap);
```

and build,deploy app on emulator...image is still attached to **_imageView** after taking pic. Anything changed, even when i delete all lines working on **_imageView** and program still attaching image do **_imageView**.

Someone know what cause this situation? I need to observe the changes in the working of the program but now i can't. I am new to xamarin so please give me solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dealt with this a lot, way I've found to solve it is a full reinstall:

- Menu -> settings -> apps
- find your app, click and click uninstall
- wait for the confirmation of the uninstall
- shutdown the emulator
- **clean and rebuild** to be safe
- redeploy

This also deals with app crashes on first deployments too.

Comment: Only if they don't build, for most of my Xamarin projects I find reinstalling the app fixes 99% of problems if redeploying doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Visual Studio, select tool  options - > projects and solutions -> build and run -> set "on Run option" to "Always build".